# Setting X-many bits as an integer X

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation

How do I shorten the following C snippet?
Basically, given an integer X, I want to set X many bits.

```
for(i=0;i<NUM; i++){
    u32Mask |= (0x1 << i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    if(i == 32)                   // X86 ignores shift count of 32
        u32mask = 0xffffffffu;
    else
        u32mask = (1u << i) - 1;
```

or as commented by BeeOnRope

```
    uint32_t tbl[33] =
       {0x00000000u,0x00000001u,0x00000003u,0x00000007u,
        0x0000000fu,0x0000001fu,0x0000003fu,0x0000007fu,
        0x000000ffu,0x000001ffu,0x000003ffu,0x000007ffu,
        0x00000fffu,0x00001fffu,0x00003fffu,0x00007fffu,
        0x0000ffffu,0x0001ffffu,0x0003ffffu,0x0007ffffu,
        0x000fffffu,0x001fffffu,0x003fffffu,0x007fffffu,
        0x00ffffffu,0x01ffffffu,0x03ffffffu,0x07ffffffu,
        0x0fffffffu,0x1fffffffu,0x3fffffffu,0x7fffffffu,
        0xffffffff};
    // ...
    u32mask = tbl[i];
```

Comment: Yes, this. Or on the rare platform with terrible variable shift performance you could use a 32-entry lookup table which gives the answer directly.